# tidyverse/ggplot2: subsetting by a factor that is used in manual scales?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a large and complex dataset, but the important parts boil down to something similar to this:

```
my_df <- data.frame(Expt = rep(c("Expt1", "Expt2", "Expt3", "Expt4"), each = 96),
                  ExpType = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 192),
                  Treatment = c(rep("T1", 192), rep("T2", 144), rep("T1", 48)),
                  Subject = c(rep(c("S01", "S02", "S03", "S04", "S05", "S06", "S07", "S08"), 24), rep("S01", 96), rep("S06", 96)),
                  xvar = as.factor(rep(rep(c(10, 5, 2.5, 1.25, 0.6, 0.3, 0.16, 0.08, 0.04, 0.02, 0, "NA"), each = 8),  4)),
                  yvar = runif(384))
```

I'm currently grouping my data by ExpType and Treatment, calculating some summary statistics, and then graphing, like so:

```
myplots <- my_df %>%
  group_by(ExpType, Treatment) %>%  #  took out Include because I'm using the versions with no questionable data
  nest() %>%

  mutate(sumstats = map(
    .x = data,
    ~.x %>%
      group_by(Subject, xvar) %>%
      summarize(
        my_mean = mean(yvar, na.rm = TRUE)
      )))  %>%

  mutate(plots1 = map2(
    .x = data,
    .y = sumstats,
    ~ggplot(data = .x) +
      theme_classic() +
      scale_shape_manual(name = "Subject", values = c("S01" = 23, "S02" = 24, "S03" = 21, "S04" = 21, "S05" = 22, "S06" = 22, "S07" = 24, "S08" = 25)) + 
      scale_linetype_manual(name = "Subject", values = c("S01" = "solid", "S02" = "dotted", "S03" = "dotted", "S04" = "solid", "S05" = "dotted", "S06" = "dashed", "S07" = "solid", "S08" = "dashed")) +
      scale_fill_manual(name = "Subject", values = c("S01" = "#AA4499", "S02" = "#882255", "S03" = "#CC6677", "S04" = "#DDCC77", "S05" = "#999933", "S06" = "#117733", "S07" = "#44AA99", "S08" = "#88CCEE")) +
      scale_color_manual(name = "Subject", values = c("S01" = "#AA4499", "S02" = "#882255", "S03" = "#CC6677", "S04" = "#DDCC77", "S05" = "#999933", "S06" = "#117733", "S07" = "#44AA99", "S08" = "#88CCEE")) +
      geom_line(data = .y, aes(x=xvar, y = my_mean, group=Subject,  color=Subject, linetype = Subject)) +
      geom_point(aes(x=xvar, y = yvar, group=Subject, fill=Subject, shape = Subject), size = 2.5)

  ))

walk(.x = myplots$plots1,  ~print(.x))
```

This is great, but I have enough Subjects that it's hard to see what's going on, and I'd like to be able to make separate graphs for each Subject.  I can facet by Subject, but there are enough of them that the graphs are really small and it's hard to see what's going on.

Where/how do I add in this extra subsetting step, and still pass the factor to the manual scales?

Comment: To clarify, you would like to group by ExpType + Treatment + Subject, yet be able to access Subject's values in the ggplot object?

Comment: Yes; I'd like to still be able to use the Subject to set aesthetic parameters (point/line style).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

A simple way to access Subject's values from each nested dataset while keeping it as a grouping variable outside the nesting is to make a duplicate column with the same values:

```
# define manual scale palettes outside for easy reusability
shape.pal <- c(23, 24, 21, 21, 22, 22, 24, 25)
linetype.pal <- c("solid", "dotted", "dotted", "solid", "dotted", "dashed", "solid", "dashed")
fill.pal <- c("#AA4499", "#882255", "#CC6677", "#DDCC77", "#999933", "#117733", "#44AA99", "#88CCEE")
names(shape.pal) <- names(linetype.pal) <- names(fill.pal) <- paste0("S0", seq(1, 8))
```

```
myplots <- my_df %>%
  mutate(Subject2 = Subject) %>% # add a duplicate column for subject
  group_by(ExpType, Treatment, Subject2) %>% # don't next duplicate subject column
  nest() %>%

  mutate(sumstats = map(
    .x = data,
    ~.x %>%
      group_by(Subject, xvar) %>%
      summarize(
        my_mean = mean(yvar, na.rm = TRUE)
      )))  %>%

  mutate(plots1 = map2(
    .x = data,
    .y = sumstats,
    ~ggplot(data = .x, 
            aes(x = xvar, y = yvar, group = Subject)) +
      geom_line(data = .y, 
                aes(y = my_mean, color = Subject, linetype = Subject)) +
      geom_point(aes(fill = Subject, shape = Subject), 
                 size = 2.5) +
      labs(shape = "Subject", linetype = "Subject", fill = "Subject", colour = "Subject") +
      scale_shape_manual(values = shape.pal) + 
      scale_linetype_manual(values = linetype.pal) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = fill.pal, aesthetics = c("fill", "color")) +
      theme_classic()
  ))

walk(.x = myplots$plots1,  ~print(.x))
```

Resulting plot corresponding to ExpType = A, Treatment = T1, Subject = S01:

[image: plot 1]

## Solution 2

More generally, you can access the grouping variables if you use `pmap` instead of `map2` in creating the ggplot objects, as `pmap` allows you to map over more than 2 inputs simultaneously.

Demonstration below, which also maps over ExpType & Treatment to reflect each plot's combination of grouping variables' values in its plot title:

```
myplots <- my_df %>%
  group_by(ExpType, Treatment, Subject) %>% # use subject as a grouping variable
  group_nest() %>%

  mutate(sumstats = map(
    .x = data,
    ~.x %>%
      group_by(xvar) %>% # not grouping by subject here, as it's not a column in data
      summarize(
        my_mean = mean(yvar, na.rm = TRUE)
      )))  %>%

  mutate(plots1 = pmap(
    .l = list(x = data,
              y = sumstats,
              s = as.character(Subject),
              z = as.character(ExpType),
              w = as.character(Treatment)),
    function(x, y, s, z, w) ggplot(data = x, aes(x = xvar, group = s)) +
      geom_line(data = y, 
                aes(y = my_mean, color = s, linetype = s)) +
      geom_point(aes(y = yvar, fill = s, shape = s), 
                 size = 2.5) +
      labs(title = paste0("ExpType: ", z, ", Treatment: ", w),
           shape = "Subject", linetype = "Subject", fill = "Subject", colour = "Subject") +
      scale_shape_manual(values = shape.pal) + 
      scale_linetype_manual(values = linetype.pal) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = fill.pal, aesthetics = c("fill", "colour")) +
      theme_classic()     
  ))

walk(.x = myplots$plots1,  ~print(.x))
```

Resulting plot corresponding to ExpType = A, Treatment = T1, Subject = S01:

[image: plot 2]

Comment: Thanks!  That's really helpful.